# Microsoft Teams Call API

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We had changed to Microsoft Teams Calls in my Organization. No we want to retrive informations (Phone Number) from every incoming and outgoing Calls at start and endtime in our own Application. Is there any API etc. that makes that possible?

Thanks in advance
Swess72

Comment: Currently there is no API available for this scenario. Could you please help by suggesting this feature at [Microsoft Teams Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft Graph API for PSTN calls.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unfortunately, this API does not give instant feedback.